# Casting a child to the parent issue in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

```
class Parent {
    int i = 60;
}

class Child extends Parent {
    int i = 70;
}

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child c = new Child();
        Parent p = new Parent();

        System.out.println((Parent c).i);
    }

}
```

Here I want to print a `Parent` class variable (i.e. `i = 60`) with the help of a `Child` class object. How can I do that?

Comment: `((Parent) c).i`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
System.out.println(((Parent) c).i);
```

The *simplified* template for casting an `EXPRESSION` or a `VARIABLE` to a `TYPE` is:

```
((TYPE)(EXPRESSION|VARIABLE))
```

Comment: Can use super() to do so?

Comment: @MYPC, we can't. `super()` is used to refer to a parent constructor and doesn't take part in any expressions

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need

```
class Parent{
    int i = 60;
}

class Child extends Parent{
    int i = 70;
}

class TreeMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child c = new Child();
        Parent p = new Parent();

        System.out.println(((Parent) c).i);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
System.out.println(((Parent)c).i);
```